# How can I go about building an RDF store with Cassandra as backend?

Tags: cassandra

I've been given a task of using Cassandra as the backend for storing RDF statements. I've so far managed to use Sesame RIO API to parse OWL converting it into RDF statements and then storing the same statements in Cassandra with Subject as the key. The catch here is to let SPARQL queries to work on RDF data stored in Cassandra. In essence, it is about mimicking the functionality of Sesame repository with Cassandra as backend inheriting the scaling features and robustness of Cassandra.

What point is a good point to start looking at? The changes I need to do in the Cassandra project code in order to implement such a functionality? Also, to index the RDF data and to make it SPARQueryable? Checklist?

I'm in need of some suggestions since I seem to be getting nowhere with this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why you would want to change Cassandra. Surely you model something that encapsulates all your needs, then write either a custom driver to talk to Cassandra, or (probably easier) some kind of middleware to translate from your SPARQueryable to CQL/Thrift.

Comment: FWIW (Sesame dev here), Sesame precisely is set up to play the role of that middleware. It's the Sesame SAIL API you should be looking at.